# What is meant by this error? Argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(int a)"

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-call, function-parameter

I am trying to use a function pointer to call another function, but it gives me an error. I don't understand the error.

Here's my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void print(void (*ptr)(int));
void printint(int);

int main()
{
    char a;
    int b;
    scanf("%c %d",&a,&b);
    print(printint(b));
    return 0;
} 

void print(void (*ptr)(int a))
{
    ptr(a);
}

void printint(int a)
{
    // printf("executed");
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

I think I wrongly used the function pointer. Can someone explain how to implement this program in the correct way?

Comment: `printint(b)` returns `void`. You probably wanted `print(printint);`, but you need to pass the parameter separately.

Comment: Is this C or C++? This looks 100% C.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by `print(printint(b));`? You can only pass a pointer-to-function to `print`, not a full expression which evaluates to `void` (that is, `printint(b)` does not return anything)

Comment: so u saying i cant pass a integer to a function pointer which has the address of printint?

Comment: @Vinoth you can, but not the way you are trying to do it

Comment: i understood now, thank u so much..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `print(printint(b));` is *calling* `printint(b)` first and then passing its *return value* (which is `void`) to `print()`.  Hence the error.

You need to pass the `b` value to `print()` in a separate parameter, and then it can pass the value to `printint()`, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*funcptr)(int);

void print(funcptr, int);
void printint(int);

int main()
{
    char a;
    int b;
    scanf("%c %d", &a, &b);
    print(printint, b);
    return 0;
} 

void print(funcptr ptr, int a)
{
    ptr(a);
}

void printint(int a)
{
    // printf("executed");
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `printint(b)` is `void`, according to the function `printint` declaration:

```
void printint(int);
```

So, instead of passing a function pointer, you are passing `void` in this call:

```
print(printint(b));
```

The function `print` should be declared like this:

```
void print( void (*ptr)(int), int );
```

and called like this:

```
print( printint, b );
```

Correspondingly, the function should be defined like this:

```
void print( void (*ptr)(int ), int a )
{
    ptr(a);
}
```